# "Warnings" while creating user with adduser

Tags: 14.04, system, adduser

While creating a system user using `adduser`, it responded with a lot of entries like the following:

```
myser@machine:~$ sudo adduser --system backup_user
Adding system user `backup_user' (UID 108) ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Adding new user `backup_user' (UID 108) with group `nogroup' ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Creating home directory `/home/backup_user' ...
```

What those `sent invalidate` lines mean? Is something I should be worried about?

Comment: Has the user been created? What else happened?

Comment: Yes the user was created and everything seems to be fine. But I never seen that output, so I was wondering if there is something wrong with this machine...

Comment: This might be an Azure thing? Are you on Azure? https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3d9bcd/ubuntu_on_azure_sent_invalidate_passwdgroup/

Comment: @SimonWoodside Yes, this was in an Azure VM

Answer (score 3):

It is apparently not a problem.

Accessing the local user, group and passwd file is simple enough, but if you want lookups to include ldap, or nis over the network it can be useful to have a caching daemon to speed things up.  It is this caching mechanism that is reporting these misleading messages to you.

See the man page on nscd (or similar).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's not an issue, but you can get rid of it by removing the name caching server:

`sudo apt-get remove unscd`